# Is there any difference between “of who we are as a people” and “of ours as a people”?

Tags: meaning, grammar, relative-clauses

> 1. Donald Trump appealed to the very worst, most base instincts of who we are as a people.
> 2. Donald Trump appealed to the very worst, most base instincts of ours as a people.

The first sentence is from an article from The New Yorker. I understand what it mean but the expression is a little unusual for me so I wonder if I could replace "of who we are as a people" with "of us as a people".

Comment: Do people have base instincts, or does the identity of people? Which makes sense?

Comment: How do they mean the same?

Comment: @Kris The first one is what I read on a report from The New Yorker. I understand its meaning but this expression is kind of unusual for me.If I was the author I might put it as in the second sentence. I wondered if they’re different.Are you saying they are completely different to you?

Comment: @ZaneHsu a much more appropriate rewrite would be "... to our very worst, most base instincts."  Saying "of us" feels awkward and/or wrong.

Comment: @Hellion Thanks!